# Cannot read property 'concat' of null - when trying to post query to graphql endpoint

Tags: c#, json, .net, graphql

This is my query:-

```
query Sessions(
  $appID: ID!,
  $newestCursor: String,
  $oldestCursor: String,
  $cursor: String,
  $date: Float,
  $filters: [SessionFilter!],
  $groupedFilters: [[SessionFilter!]!],
  $retentionMonths: Int,
  $disablePagination: Boolean,
  $sourceAppID: String,
  $exactCount: Boolean) {
    app(id: $appID, sourceAppID: $sourceAppID) {
      appID
      sessionInfo (
        newestCursor: $newestCursor,
        oldestCursor: $oldestCursor,
        cursor: $cursor, 
        date: $date, 
        filters: $filters,
        groupedFilters: $groupedFilters,
        retentionMonths: $retentionMonths,
        disablePagination: $disablePagination,
        exactCount: $exactCount) {
          sessions {
            browserInfo {
              href
              useragent
              platform
              __typename
            }
            deviceInfo {
              deviceName
              deviceType
              manufacturer
              release
              __typename
            }
            user {
              name
              email
              userID
              isAnonymous
              __typename
            }
            location {
              country
              region
              city
              ip
              __typename 
            }
            activity {
              videoTime
              start
              end
              href
              __typename
            }
            date
            id
            duration
            eventCount
            hasIntercomShow
            hasZendeskShow
            isDeleted
            __typename
          }
          cursor
          newestCursor
          nextCursor
          prevCursor
          sessionOffset
          sessionCount
          isEstimatedCount
          scanInfo {
            count
            total
            horizon
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
    }
```

When I use the above as request body in postman it works fine but when I try to serialize this to JSON and make a request to a graphql endpoint I get the following error:-

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'concat' of null",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "app",
        "sessionInfo"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ]
```

My .net code below:-

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel, jsonSettings);       //requestModel contains the query
var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await SendRequest(method, uri, content, token);
```

What am I doing wrong?